# Contrasts can be applied only to factor

Tags: r, variables

I have a question about R.

I am using a test called levene.test to test a homogeneity of variance.

I know that you need a factor variable with at least two levels in order for this to work. And from what I see, I do have at least two levels for the factor variable that I am using. But somehow I keep getting the error of:

```
> nocorlevene <- levene.test(geno1rs11809462$SIF1, geno1rs11809462$k, correction.method = "correction.factor")

    Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
      contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
```

I even try generate a variable from a binomial distribution:

```
k<-rbinom(1304, 1, 0.5)
```

and then use that as a factor, but is still not working.

Lastly I create a variable with 3 levels:

```
k<-sample(c(1,0,2), 1304, replace=T)
```

but some how still not working and getting the same error of:

> nocorlevene <- levene.test(geno1rs11809462$SIF1, geno1rs11809462$k, correction.method="zero.removal")

```
Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
```

This is the output of the type of the variable in the data:

```
> str(geno1rs11809462)
'data.frame':   1304 obs. of  16 variables:
 $ id           : chr  "WG0012669-DNA_A03_K05743" "WG0012669-DNA_A04_K05752" "WG0012669-DNA_A05_K05761" "WG0012669-DNA_A06_K05785" ...
 $ rs11809462   : Factor w/ 2 levels "2/1","2/2": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr  "WG0012669-DNA_A03_K05743" "WG0012669-DNA_A04_K05752" "WG0012669-DNA_A05_K05761" "WG0012669-DNA_A06_K05785" ...
 $ FID          : chr  "9370" "9024" "14291" "4126" ...
 $ AGE_CALC     : num  61 47 NA 62.5 55.6 59.7 46.6 41.2 NA 46.6 ...
 $ MREFSUM      : num  185 325 NA 211 212 ...
 $ NORSOUTH     : Factor w/ 3 levels "0","1","NA": 1 1 3 1 1 1 1 1 3 1 ...
 $ smoke1       : Factor w/ 3 levels "0","1","NA": 2 2 3 1 1 1 2 1 3 1 ...
 $ smoke2       : Factor w/ 3 levels "0","1","NA": 1 1 3 2 2 2 1 2 3 2 ...
 $ ANYCG60      : num  0 0 NA 1 0 0 0 0 NA 1 ...
 $ DCCT_HBA_MEAN: num  7.39 6.93 NA 7.37 7.56 7.86 6.22 8.88 NA 8.94 ...
 $ EDIC_HBA     : num  7.17 7.63 NA 8.66 9.68 7.74 6.59 9.34 NA 7.86 ...
 $ HBAEL        : num  7.3 8.82 NA 9.1 9.3 ...
 $ ELDTED_HBA   : num  7.23 7.76 NA 8.36 9.21 7.92 6.64 9.64 NA 9.09 ...
 $ SIF1         : num  19.6 17 NA 23.8 24.1 ...
 $ sex          : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ k            : Factor w/ 3 levels "0","1","2": 1 1 2 3 1 3 3 3 1 2 ...
```

As you can see the variable k, sex have 3 and 2 levels respectively but somehow I still get that error message.

```
> head(geno1rs11809462)
                        id rs11809462   FID AGE_CALC  MREFSUM NORSOUTH smoke1 smoke2 ANYCG60
1 WG0012669-DNA_A03_K05743        2/2  9370     61.0 184.5925        0      1      0       0
2 WG0012669-DNA_A04_K05752        2/2  9024     47.0 325.0047        0      1      0       0
3 WG0012669-DNA_A05_K05761        2/2 14291       NA       NA       NA     NA     NA      NA
4 WG0012669-DNA_A06_K05785        2/2  4126     62.5 211.2557        0      0      1       1
5 WG0012669-DNA_A08_K05802        2/2 11280     55.6 212.2922        0      0      1       0
6 WG0012669-DNA_A09_K05811        2/2 11009     59.7 261.0116        0      0      1       0
  DCCT_HBA_MEAN EDIC_HBA HBAEL ELDTED_HBA    SIF1 sex k
1          7.39     7.17  7.30       7.23 19.6136   0 0
2          6.93     7.63  8.82       7.76 17.0375   0 0
3            NA       NA    NA         NA      NA   1 1
4          7.37     8.66  9.10       8.36 23.8333   1 2
5          7.56     9.68  9.30       9.21 24.1338   1 0
6          7.86     7.74  8.53       7.92 25.7272   1 2
```

If anyone can give me some hints as to why this is happening, it would be great. I just don't know why the variable k or sex or having different levels are giving me error when I run the test.

thank you

Comment: You might get better luck finding an answer on Cross-Validated: http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Please post a reproducible example.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error with the example data.

Comment: Hi Sven, does that mean you don't get the same error when you use my data? because I do get the error message.

Comment: sorry I am posting there because I thought I will get more response from there.

Comment: @robbrit, I respectfully disagree: this is a coding problem rather than a statistical problem.

Comment: Not an answer, but a hint: what is the result of `with(geno1rs11809462,table(is.na(SIF1),k))`?  I suspect that one of your factor levels has all `NA` values, which leads to a factor with not enough levels ...

Comment: > with(genors12726733, table(is.na(SIF1), k))
       k
          0   1   2
  FALSE 357 372 353
  TRUE   73  82  67

Comment: Hi Ben, I have added the output above. Sorry I am not sure how to make it looks like a table. I just paste the output from R.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think I may have solved the problem. I believe it is due to NA value in the data. Because after I removed the na using say

```
x<-na.omit(original_data)
```

then apply the levene test on x, the warning message disappears.

Hopefully this is the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 7):

If your factor has only one level, you will get this error. To check to see the levels of your factor variables, use `lapply(df, levels)`. It will return nothing for non-factor variables, but will easily let you identify which variable is the offender. This is especially helpful if, like me, you have hundreds of variables.

Answer (score 2):

You need to actually convert your variable to a `factor`.   Just having three (or a finite) number of values does not necessarily make it a factor.

use    `x <- factor(x)`  to convert

---

When you look at the output of `str()`, it shows you the type of each variable:

```
<..cropped..>
$ SIF1         : num  19.6 17 NA 23.8 24.1 ...
$ sex          : Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 ...
$ k            : Factor w/ 3 levels "0","1","2": 1 1 2 3 1 3 3 3 1 2 ...
```

notice that `$k` is a `factor` but `SIF1` is not
Thus, use

```
 geno1rs11809462$SIF1 <- factor(geno1rs11809462$SIF1)
```

Comment: Hi, I think they are already factor variable (sex or k). This is what I have:> class(geno1rs11809462$k)
[1] "factor"
> class(geno1rs11809462$sex)
[1] "factor"
> attributes(geno1rs11809462$k))
Error: unexpected ')' in "attributes(geno1rs11809462$k))"
> attributes(geno1rs11809462$k)
$levels
[1] "0" "1" "2"

$class
[1] "factor"

> attributes(geno1rs11809462$sex)
$levels
[1] "0" "1"

$class
[1] "factor"

Comment: hi @john_w, please edit what you copy and paste. If there is an error or typo, please remove it before posting

Comment: @john_w, you are not using the variable `sex` in your test. you are using the variable `SIF1`.  See your post:  "`levene.test(geno1rs11809462$SIF1, geno1rs11809462$k, correction.method = "correction.factor")`"

Comment: Hi Ricardo, the SIF1 variable is a continuous variable. So I don't think this variable called SIF1 should be treated as factor. Is it right?