# Need predictor to act as a factor

Tags: r

Trying to get the predictor "geology" to act as a factor...it says it is at the raster level, in the rasterstack, and in the dataframe, so not sure why it won't work.

```
is.factor(geology)
# [1] TRUE
is.factor(tstack$geology)
# [1] TRUE
is.factor(mbdata$geology)
# [1] TRUE

library(gam)
mel.gam.forw <- gam(mel.bur ~ s(aus35.s,3) + s(firefreq.s,4) + geology + 
                    s(slope.s,2) + s(wetness.s,3), family = binomial (link="logit"), 
                    data = mbdata)

mb.gam.f.pred <- predict(tstack, mel.gam.forw, type="response")

Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contrasts.arg[[nn]]) : 
  contrasts apply only to factors
In addition: Warning message:
In model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, na.action = na.action, xlev = object$xlevels) :
  variable 'geology' is not a factor
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: My guess that is that `geology` is being coerced to something other than a factor.  Could you check the other inputs to make sure that everything which should be a factor in fact is a factor?

Comment: Geology is the only input that needs to be a factor

Comment: So it's failing on the call to `predict()` and not the call to `gam()` ?

Comment: Please check to make sure that you don't have any `NA` values in the factor variable, q.v. [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20645926/contrasts-can-be-applied-only-to-factor) which discusses this.

Comment: Saw that post before, tried it (geology <- na.omit(geology)) and checked it was still saying it was a factor...ran predict() again and same error @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Isn't `predict` taking first "model", then "newdata" argument?

Comment: is your predict statement correct ... notmall it is `predict(gam.object, gam.newdata ... `. You seem to have it reversed

Comment: @user20650 that was a photofinish, well played. :)

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, sorry @RomanLuštrik

Comment: ha, and to you... now  i need to do is work on my spelling

Comment: try `predict(mel.gam.forw, tstack, type="response")`

Comment: > mb.gam.f.pred <- predict(mel.gam.forw, tstack, type="response")
Error in as.data.frame.default(data) : 
  cannot coerce class "structure("RasterStack", package = "raster")" to a data.frame @user20650

Comment: It would appear @user20650 and I were wrong. `predict` for `Raster*` is different (grrrr). See the [docs](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/raster/docs/predict).

Comment: Thanks anyway. Any other thoughts? Still stuck... @RomanLuštrik

Comment: At this point I will ask for a reproducible example.