# contrasts can be applied to only factor in R

Tags: r

I am trying to fit a logistic regression to my data, but I get this error:

```
logistic <- lm(response ~., data = df_without, family='binomial')

Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) : 
  contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
```

Unlike the two other questions on this topic ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20645926/contrasts-can-be-applied-only-to-factor) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18171246/error-in-contrasts-when-defining-a-linear-model-in-r)), I have >=2 levels for all my factors, and my response variable has 2 levels as well:

```
summary(df_without$response)
     0      1 
123534  64591 


summary(df_without[sapply(df_without, is.factor)])
```

[image]

My dataframe is available [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1zdv264rrvzat3c/df_without.Rdata?dl=0) as an .Rdata file.

sessionInfo()

```
R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.10.1 (Yosemite)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] parallel  splines   stats     graphics  grDevices utils         datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] Amelia_1.7.3        Rcpp_0.11.6         randomForest_4.6-10 e1071_1.6-4         plyr_1.8.2         
 [6] gbm_2.1.1           survival_2.38-1     glmnet_2.0-2            foreach_1.4.2       Matrix_1.2-0       
[11] caret_6.0-47        ggplot2_1.0.1       lattice_0.20-31     lubridate_1.3.3     RJDBC_0.2-5        
[16] rJava_0.9-6         DBI_0.3.1          

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_3.2.0      nloptr_1.0.4        class_7.3-12        iterators_1.0.7     tools_3.2.0        
 [6] digest_0.6.8        lme4_1.1-7          memoise_0.2.1       nlme_3.1-120        gtable_0.1.2       
[11] mgcv_1.8-6          brglm_0.5-9         SparseM_1.6         proto_0.3-10        BradleyTerry2_1.0-6
[16] stringr_1.0.0       gtools_3.5.0        grid_3.2.0          nnet_7.3-9          foreign_0.8-63     
[21] minqa_1.2.4         reshape2_1.4.1      car_2.0-25          magrittr_1.5        scales_0.2.4       
[26] codetools_0.2-11    MASS_7.3-40         pbkrtest_0.4-2      colorspace_1.2-6    quantreg_5.11      
[31] stringi_0.4-1       munsell_0.4.2
```

Comment: is it possible when the missing observstions have been removed (as happens in `lm`) that some variables only have one level? try `summary(na.omit(df_without)[sapply(df_without, is.factor)])` (untested)

Comment: oh and you are maybe missing a `g`

Comment: Really? A 10.87 MB file????

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know that code only answers are hunted down and dealt with severely by the moderators but this really does speak for itself:

```
 # I did download the excessively large file
> table(df_without[ complete.cases(df_without), 'pymnt_plan'])

        n    y 
   0 1231    0
```

Comment: ... and therefore `logistic <- glm(response ~. - pymnt_plan, data = df_without, family='binomial')` should work nicely

Comment: @BenBolker:  Well, maybe not. There are three columns with lots of missing data: `$ mths_since_last_delinq  $ mths_since_last_record $ mths_since_last_major_derog` so I suspect some effort needs to be focused on understanding what that actually means. It may be  favorable feature in terms of risk assessment to never have had a delinquency or a "derog" (whatever a 'derog' might be, but it doesn't sound good). The right answer may be ... Look at your data _First_; Don't wait until you get a flakey result.