# Logistic Regression - Contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels

Tags: r, logistic-regression, factors

> ```
> Error in `contrasts<-`(`*tmp*`, value = contr.funs[1 + isOF[nn]]) :   
> contrasts can be applied only to factors with 2 or more levels
> ```

I keep getting the above error when trying to run

```
model<- glm(asb_flag ~ ., family=binomial(link='logit'), data=dev)
```

**Although, all of my factors have more than one level.**

Comment: See here... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20645926/contrasts-can-be-applied-only-to-factor.  Maybe it is due to `NA`s.

Comment: I fixed it, it was because I had factors they actually needed to be changed to characters.