# How to solve this unexpected Error in Glm Function in R?

Tags: r, glm

Kindly help through this mess, I cant get what the issue behind this error is.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhlVZ.png)

Comment: check your data for factor variables with only one level, e.g. lapply(train, nevels)

Comment: or similarly for string columns: lengths(lapply(Filter(is.character, train), unique))

Comment: try 'binomial' instead of binomial only

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Can you please post your code in a text format rather than as a (link to) an image? Images are unsearchable and inaccessible to people using screen readers ...  A [mcve] would be nice, but in the absence of that could you please also edit your question to include the output of `str(train)`?  See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49083065/contrasts-can-only-be-applied-to-factors-with-at-least-two-levels

Comment: If the linked answer does *not* answer your question, please edit your question to explain how your problem differs, and high-rep users can vote to re-open it ...